# How can i use the newest app engine sdk for java (with maven or eclipse)?

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, gae-eclipse-plugin, maven-gae-plugin

I wanted to start using GAE with Java but i am still struggling with the tooling.

My first try was using Eclipse with the "Google Plugin for Eclipse". I got it running, but when debugging i get the information, that my sdk is outdated.
So i ask myself, how i can update the SDK on my own. Furthermore i have the feeling, this is no more the way to go because the Pluging/SDK is not updated anymore and there are many hints for IntelliJ as IDE to choose.

So i went on with the documentation and found the maven-way. Set everything up again and getting also an information, that the sdk is out of date, when i run `mvn appengine:devserver`

```
[INFO] There is a new version of the SDK available.
[INFO] -----------
[INFO] Latest SDK:
[INFO] Release: 1.9.46
[INFO] Timestamp: Wed Oct 19 03:22:06 CEST 2016
[INFO] API versions: [1.0]
[INFO]
[INFO] -----------
[INFO] Your SDK:
[INFO] Release: 1.9.22
[INFO] Timestamp: Sat Jul 11 00:55:48 CEST 2015
[INFO] API versions: [1.0]
```

When i check the pom.xml i can see a reason for it:

```
<appengine.sdk.version>1.9.24</appengine.sdk.version>
```

But these versions dont match and just increasing version number doesnt work because maven wont find the repositories.

So again i ask myself, if the documentaion is still the way to go.

Next way i tried then is using "gcloud" command-line tools, but i am now at a point again where i miss documentation.

So my question is, how i can i use the current SDK?

What is the "best tooling" at the moment to start developing java gae apps, as all my tries till now seem to be outdated. Ant? Maven? Eclipse? IntelliJ? AndroidStudio?

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version is 1.9.46 as of 8-Nov-2016. You can check this [page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/download)

For accessing using Maven, use this code

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.appengine/appengine-api-1.0-sdk -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
    <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.44</version>
</dependency>
```

You can keep a watch on this [page](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.appengine/appengine-api-1.0-sdk)

Additionally, I am also experimenting GAE with Maven in Eclipse. Hope, we can discuss to get a fruitful result. You can get in touch me at aponmyway@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Jello Framework](http://jello-framework.com//). It is a Java framework for GAE (Disclaimer - I am the author).

You can try the [Getting started guide](http://jello-framework.com/guide/getting-started.html) which will get you up and running in eclipse in less then 30 minutes.